# Only want score and latent from pca in Matlab to save memory

Tags: matlab, memory, pca

Is there a way to assign the coefficient variable NULL when running PCA? I'm only interested in the score and latent values but it's too big of a file to just run

```
[coeff, score, latent] = pca(myData);
```

and then clear coeff after. Is there a way to assign it NULL instead? like

```
[NULL, score, latent = pca(myData);
```

or is there a way to efficiently extract just the score and latent? Subsequently, I'm assigning these two values to a .mat file using

```
m1 = matfile('myotherdatafile.mat', 'Writable', true);

m2 = matfile('myotherdatafile2.mat', 'Writable', true);

m1.Dpts=score;

m2.Dpts=latent;
```

Alternatively is there a way to nest above commands so that latent and score are not saved into memory? Something like:

```
[coeff, m1.Dpts, m2.Dpts] = pca(myData);
```

Or another way to access the pca data? My input data is 93 million x 54 if that's important. Thank you for you help!

Potential sample code:

```
 myData = zeros(93000000,54);
```

Comment: Try `[~, score, latent] = pca(myData);` The tilde is used to denote values you're not interested in after the function call is made.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!